# node.js loads html fine, but does not load associated css

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm having trouble using javascript to load my index.html file (which I'm pretty sure is probably the 5th easiest thing to do in javascript).

I'll try to keep this short; basically, my index.html loads fine WITH css when I open it manually (pictured below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZfbq.png

When I load it using javascript however, it only loads plain html with default formatting, and WITHOUT my css:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eovav.png

the files are located as follows:

server.js in: root

index.html in: root/public

style.css in: root/public/css

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var handleRequest = function handleRequest(request, response){
        if (request.url==='/index.html' || request.url==='/') {
            response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
            fs.readFile('./public/index.html', function (err, file) {
                if (err) throw err;
                response.end(file);
            });
        } else {
            response.writeHeader(404);
            response.end('Are you lost friend?');
        }
}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
var PORT = 8080; 
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My not-so-amazing Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>The Inspiratorator v5.7.0</h1>

<p>I AM THE SUN</p>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
h1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  backface-visibility: 0.5; 
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
   background-color: blue;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: Is this node.js? You may want to mention that in the tags and maybe in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how you are handling the requests, basically you are denying every request except `/`. The browser cannot reach the css file.

```
if (request.url==='/index.html' || request.url==='/') {
            response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
            fs.readFile('./public/index.html', function (err, file) {
                if (err) throw err;
                response.end(file);
            });
        } else {
            response.writeHeader(404);
            response.end('Are you lost friend?');
        }
```

Here I added an exception for css file and it works.

**NOTE:**

You should change this code to make for your needs, don't use in production.

```
} else if (request.url.indexOf('css') != -1) {
            response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-type':'text/css'});
            fs.readFile('./public/css/style.css', function (err, file) {
                if (err) throw err;
                response.end(file);
            });
        }
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great; just to make sure I under the code correctly, would checking inside the (if (request.url==='/index.html' || request.url==='/')) for css content and then reading the file work? And is there a way to read the file through the path specified in the HTML document or do I have to manually state it? (or set up some sort of naming convention, i.e. stylethispage.css for thispage.html)

Comment: Oh nevermind, that didn't work, and I think I get why - I'm pretty sure I was misunderstanding how the page was loading. When the user request the html page (and javascript GETs it), the html page would then request the css file on its own, which wouldn't get sent through because it was just defaulting to 404; is that right? Still a bit confused as to whether there's a 'proper' way to do this, perhaps by obtaining the file that is 'sent' from the html page or something? (still not a 100% positive on how it all works)

Comment: @OmarA.Yousry Yes that's how HTTP works. The proper way is to use something higher lever maybe `express.js`?

Comment: Ah okay, I'll definitely look into it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You are literally returning http 404 unless the uri ends with index.html, so how could the css be served like this?

Use a proper debugger like the one in Chrome or Firebug to find the reason for such errors.